# Is there any alternative for Android Share intent not working after 5.0 poperly?

Tags: android, share-intent

I am creating message having text and url. But when I call share intent it only shows Extra text (that is for link) , doesn't show extra subject( that is for text), is there any solution for that?

Comment: post some code will you?

Comment: The decision of what extras to use is up to the app that responds to the `Intent`. You simply provide the data. Whether that app uses all of that data is up to the developers of that app, not you. If you think that you may be creating the `Intent` incorrect, please edit your question and provide a [mcve].